# Mint 12: I can't open synaptic package manager

Tags: package-management, linux-mint, synaptic

I have Mint 12 Lisa DVD edition, 32 bit verion. I have `kde` and `gnome`. I can't open the Synaptic package manager. When I click on it, I am asked to enter my password, I do so and click `authenticate`, and then nothing happens!

I dual booted my XP, installing Mint last week and didn't have this problem. Is this problem happening because I installed `kde`?

**@Kevin**

when i type `synaptic` in a terminal i see:

a popup window that says

`starting without Administrative privileges`

and so one, i press ok and senaptic opens up!

**@Arochester** that didn't solve the problem but thanks coz you just help me update and clean my pc :) there was many packages than needed to be updated!

Comment: Open a Terminal and try the following commands one-by-one:sudo dpkg --configure -a ,
sudo apt-get -f install ,
sudo apt-get --fix-missing install ,
sudo apt-get update ,
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade , 
sudo apt-get clean ,
sudo apt-get autoremove ,
sudo apt-get update . Any errors? Does it work now?

Comment: Open a terminal and try running `synaptic` from there. Any errors?

Comment: @Kevin please read my edit

Comment: @arochester please read my edit

Comment: "when i type synaptic in a terminal i see:a popup window that says starting without Administrative privileges" Then start in Terminal with the command: sudo synaptic