# Mint 12: synaptic package manager error

Tags: x11, sudo, linux-mint, synaptic

Yesterday I had the [same issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31480/mint-12-i-cant-open-synaptic-package-manager), I solved it by running

```
sudo synaptic
```

But today I don't know what's happening, if I run `gksu synaptic` or `gksudo synaptic` they don't do anything.

If I go to root and execute these commands or execute `sudo synaptic`, I see:

```
sudo synaptic
No protocol specified

(synaptic:32377): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0.0
```

**EDIT: @Nunoxic**

I'm working on my local computer. When I do `sudo apt-get update` some stuff will be updated and some some stuff will not be updated

`E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.`

I ran `sudo apt-get update` 2 days ago. when i do `echo $DISPLAY` the output is `:0`

**@Gilles**

the output of `echo $XAUTHORITY` is nothing at all:)

the output of `sudo env | sort` is

```
COLORTERM=gnome-terminal
DISPLAY=:0.0
HOME=/root
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
LOGNAME=root
MAIL=/var/mail/root
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
SHELL=/bin/bash
SUDO_COMMAND=/usr/bin/env
SUDO_GID=0
SUDO_UID=0
SUDO_USER=root
TERM=xterm
USERNAME=root
USER=root
```

the output of `sudo xterm` is

```
No protocol specified
Warning: This program is an suid-root program or is being run by the root user.
The full text of the error or warning message cannot be safely formatted
in this environment. You may get a more descriptive message by running the
program as a non-root user or by removing the suid bit on the executable.
xterm Xt error: Can't open display: %s
```

**EDIT**

the output of  `XAUTHORITY=~/.Xauthority; sudo xterm` is

```
No protocol specified
Warning: This program is an suid-root program or is being run by the root user.
The full text of the error or warning message cannot be safely formatted
in this environment. You may get a more descriptive message by running the
program as a non-root user or by removing the suid bit on the executable.
xterm Xt error: Can't open display: %s
```

the output of `sudo -s9999 strace xterm` is

```
sudo: invalid option -- '9'
usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -L | -V
usage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-u user name|#uid]
usage: sudo -l[l] [-AknS] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-U user name] [-u
            user name|#uid] [-g groupname|#gid] [command]
usage: sudo [-AbEHknPS] [-C fd] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-u user
            name|#uid] [-g groupname|#gid] [VAR=value] [-i|-s] [<command>]
usage: sudo -e [-AknS] [-C fd] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-u user
            name|#uid] file ...
```

Comment: Try typing `echo $DISPLAY` in the terminal and paste the output. Also, are you working on your computer locally or through SSH? Thirdly, what happens if you open the terminal and type something like `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: @Nunoxic Please read my edit

Comment: I'm not sure if it will help but try the following : `sudo apt-get clean
cd /var/lib/apt
sudo mv lists lists.old
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update`

Comment: @Nunoxic when i do `sudo apt-get clean cd /var/lib/apt sudo mv lists lists.old sudo mkdir -p lists/partial sudo apt-get clean sudo apt-get update` I see `E: Command line option 'p' [from -p] is not known.`

Comment: That's rather funny. Try `--parents` instead. If that doesn't work as well try breaking that command down to `mkdir lists` and `cd lists` and finally, `mkdir partial` topped with `cd ..`

Comment: Also, please try running the commands separately instead of pasting directly from above.

Comment: @Nunoxic did that, didn't fix it :(

Comment: Please show the output of `echo $XAUTHORITY`, `sudo env | sort`, and `sudo xterm`.

Comment: @Gilles please read my edit

Comment: Let's pull up some heavier artillery. Please post the trace of `sudo -s9999 strace xterm` (it'll be huge, put it up on http://pastebin.com/ or similar if it doesn't fit in your question). Note that the trace will contain X cookies, which could give someone access to your computer in unusual circumstances; if people other than you have access to your computer, restart your X server(s) after posting (if not, you're fine).

Comment: @Gilles please read my edit and thank you for your time sir, i really appreciate it :)

Comment: Oops, sorry, typo: I meant `sudo strace -s9999 xterm`.

Comment: @Gilles please see this http://pastebin.com/2v1p577c and this http://pastebin.com/vcsA2GyX

Comment: In the output of `sudo strace -s9999 xterm`, I see that xterm is attempting a TCP connection to the X server (and failing, which is expected). With `DISPLAY=:0.0`, xterm should be making a local connection, through `/tmp/.X11-unix/X0`. Hmmm, broken permissions, maybe? What is the output of `ls -ld /tmp /tmp/.X11-unix /tmp/.X11-unix/X0`?

Comment: @Gilles I don't because Saturday, I uninstalled and reinstalled mint 12:) that's how i fixed everything lol :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible explanation is that due to some recent change the location of the X cookie file has changed from `~/.Xauthority` to some location indicated by `$XAUTHORITY`. The X cookie file contains a password that X applications must provide when connected to the X server.
(See the first part of [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10121/open-a-window-on-a-remote-x-display-why-cannot-open-display/10126#10126) for more background.)

Make sure that the `XAUTHORITY` variable is not erased by `sudo`. Run `visudo` to add this line to the `sudoers` file:

```
Defaults env_keep += XAUTHORITY
```

A related possibility is that if you don't have `XAUTHORITY` in your environment, the X cookie is stored in `~/.Xauthority`. If the `HOME` environment variable is not preserved by `sudo`, then the X applications running under `sudo` will look in `~root/.Xauthority` which doesn't have the right cookie. There are three easy ways to solve this, from most convenient to less convenient:

- Turn off the `env_reset` option in `sudoers` (when you can run arbitrary commands as the target user, there is no real security benefit to `env_reset`), and don't turn on `set_home`. This way, `~/.Xauthority` under `sudo` still refers to the calling user's home directory.
- Tell `sudo` to preserve the `XAUTHORITY` variable as above, and set `XAUTHORITY` in your X session startup file, even if it's the default value.
- Set `XAUTHORITY` using the home directory of the calling user inside the `sudo` session, e.g. by running

  ```
  sudo env XAUTHORITY=${XAUTHORITY:-~/.Xauthority} xterm
  ```

Comment: I added `Defaults env_keep += XAUTHORITY` to `sudoers` now what? the error is still there

Comment: @SomeoneLikeYou Given your environment under `sudo`, this could be a different problem locating the X cookie, see my edit.

Comment: `sudo env XAUTHORITY=${XAUTHORITY:-~/.Xauthority} xterm` gives me `No protocol specified
Warning: This program is an suid-root program or is being run by the root user.
The full text of the error or warning message cannot be safely formatted
in this environment. You may get a more descriptive message by running the
program as a non-root user or by removing the suid bit on the executable.
xterm Xt error: Can't open display: %s
` So how to do the other 2 options sir? I'm not a linux expert :)

Comment: @SomeoneLikeYou What happens if you run `export XAUTHORITY=~/.Xauthority; sudo xterm`? You may have a different, rarer problem than what I initially suspected.

Comment: you are the most helpful guy on this forum, i re-installed mint coz i had many problems :)