# How to uninstall java on Linux Mint 12

Tags: apt, software-installation, linux-mint, java

Today, I downloaded the latest java `jre` which is a **.bin** file

By mistake, I installed it on my desktop by running `./jre`. I want to remove this installation, move the **.bin** file to somewhere else and install it again

I tried `sudo apt-get remove --purge jre` gives

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Virtual packages like 'jre' can't be removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 19 not upgraded.
```

Note: I can't use synaptic package manager, [here's why](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31599/mint-12-synaptic-package-manager-error/31648#comment43265_31648), so I have to do everything from the terminal until the problem gets fixed.

The folder where the JRE is located is called **jre**.

**Edit: @stew**

just installed java jre

```
sudo echo 'deb http://www.duinsoft.nl/pkg debs all' >> /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 5CB26B26
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install update-sun-jre
```

it's the latest version. so i just have now to remove the **.bin** file and the extracted **jre** folder, would your method still works?

Why to use open jdk over jre?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first off discourage you from not using one of the java packages provided by mint unless you really need the oracle java instead of openjdk.

I'd recommend you install your java `.bin` file before removing the packaged versions of java.  After it is installed, you should use the `equivs` package in order to create a dummy `.deb` file you can install which will tell your package manager that you have a java-runtime.  This dummy package should declare it Provides the following packages: `java-runtime, java2-runtime, java5-runtime, java6-runtime java-compiler java-sdk java2-sdk java5-sdk java6-sdk` and if it is java 7, then also `java7-runtime java7-sdk`.  By doing this, you will be able to still install packages depending on a java runtime using apt-get/aptitude/synaptic/whatever.

Find help on `equivs` [here](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/apt-howto/ch-helpers.en.html) and [here](http://wiki.debian.org/CreateDummyPackage)

Then you can remove all of the various -jre (such as openjdk-7-jre) packages will declare `Provides: java-runtime`, and all the various -jdk packages will declare `Provides java-compiler`, so you can get rid of all these packaged versions with:

```
aptitude remove '~Pjava-runtime' '~Pjava-compiler'
```

Comment: please read my edit

Comment: issue fixed i guess, when i installed java, i then was able to delete the **.bin** file  :)

Answer (score 1):

A quick test with the `.bin` file obtained from http://jdk6.java.net/download.html shows that it unpacks to a new directory `jre1.6.0_32` (this might vary) current directory; hence, removing the directory should work.

As for apt-get not being able to remove it, because you installed from the `.bin` file, the install is not tracked by the package management system (apt/dpkg), thus apt-get will not solve your problem.

Finally, software installed from `.bin` files or from sources other than the package management system is put in `/opt`. This is not a standard set in stone, but is what the [FHS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) proposes.